# Insert Data From One Server To Another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

If I want to run this sort of query in SQL Server, how can I do the same query from one server I am connected to to another?

I tried adding "[ServerName1]." before "[DatabaseName1].[dbo]..." and "[ServerName2]." before "[DatabaseName2].[dbo]..." but that didn't seem to work.

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName1].[dbo].[TableName]
           ([FieldName])
     SELECT [FieldName] FROM [DatabaseName2].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you would use the server-name before the whole rest of object-name like:

```
myserver.mydatabase.dbo.mytable
```

However you first have to set up linked servers. Look up linked servers in BOL.

Comment: What is a "BOL"?

Comment: Books Online - the SQL Server help files.

Answer (score 8):

If you have [adhoc distributed queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx) enabled you can use [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx). Setting up a linked server is another option. Not sure of the pros and cons of each approach.

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName1].[dbo].[TableName]
SELECT FieldName
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
    'Data Source=Server\InstanceName;Integrated Security=SSPI')
    .DatabaseName2.dbo.TableName
```

Comment: FYI this feature has to be enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544221/how-to-enable-ad-hoc-distributed-queries

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to create a "linked server" between the two. You will need appropriate permissions to do this.

Then it's just a matter of accessing the databases using your linkedserver name.

Ex: **[linkedserver].databasename.dbo.tablename**

To create a linkedserver, go to server objects->right click on linked servers->click on 'new linked server'.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, Go to Query -> 'SQLCMD Mode'

```
DECLARE @VERSION VARCHAR(1000)
:CONNECT Soruce_Server_Name
SELECT @@VERSION AS [SQL_VERSION]
INTO 
:CONNECT Destination_Server_Name
[MSSQLTips].[dbo].[TEST]
```

Now on the Destination Server, execute your select command to check your output. For E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [CloverInfotech_DB].[dbo].[TEST]
```