# How to enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I run a query with `OPENROWSET` in SQL Server 2000 it works.

But the same query in SQL Server 2008 generates the following error:

> SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of **'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'** by using **sp_configure**

Comment: By the way, you would be better off to heed the warning and change your SQL code to use Linked Servers instead of OPENROWSET.

Comment: @RBarryYoung it's not really a "warning" - it's just a notice saying it's not enabled.  What is the danger of enabling this?

Comment: if a malicious user was able to inject SQL somewhere, turning on this option could allow them to probe data files of their choosing.  If you set it up as a Linked Server, only the specific files - Linked Servers - are exposed  (and you have your integrated SQL Server security you could be using, etc. ) .

Comment: but I do like this option for my internal testing and data migration... hence looking for how to use it again :)

Comment: This is termed as vulnerability, but is there any alternative to achieve this ?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

The following command may help you..

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: The only thing missing is that you should change 'show advanced options' back to 0

Answer (score 17):

You may check the following command

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO  --Added        
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT GroupName, Name, DepartmentID
      FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department
      ORDER BY GroupName, Name') AS a;
GO
```

Or this [documentation link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx)

Comment: you need to add a 'GO' after the 1st 'RECONFIGURE;' otherwise it's a perfect solution

Comment: don't you need to link the server before your SELECT ?

Answer (score 5):

If ad hoc updates to system catalog is "not supported", or if you get a "Msg 5808" then you will need to configure with override like this:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE with override
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE with override
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: You don't need a GO after every line