# Export sql query results to excel file on the go

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am saving my query results into a table `my_table` in SQL server 2008 and then want to insert the data from the table into an excel 2007 file. Below is the query I am using-

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT Name, Date FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT a, b FROM my_table
GO
```

It is showing following error

```
Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.
```

How can I get this fixed? P.S. Ad Hoc Distributed Queries seem to be enabled on my system.
[image]

Comment: Make sure you've enabled [Ad Hoc Distributed Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544221/how-to-enable-ad-hoc-distributed-queries).  Beware that that is a server-wide setting.  If your SQL Server is 64 bit, also take a look at [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/distributed-queries-are-configured-to-run-in-single-threaded-apartment-mode) question.  [Here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54675/openrowset-how-to-configure-ole-db-provider-to-be-used-for-for-distributed-que) is a question where someone is using the newer provider.

Comment: Is there a benefit to this over opening `testing.xls` and querying the table? Pull instead of push?

Comment: @BaconBits Ad Hoc Distributed Queries option seems to be enabled on my system. I have updated the question with a snapshot showing the configuration.

Comment: @Dick Kusleika I am not sure if this is the best way to do the job. If you have suggestions please comment!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this before your query:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

After your query set this values to 0, if you need.
You need to use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` if running 64-bit server.