# SQL error Statement, Missing Operator

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there anything wrong with this statement?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Movies INNER JOIN
     Sessions
     ON Movies.MovieID=Sessions.MovieID INNER JOIN
     Tickets
     ON Sessions.SessionID=Tickets.SessionID;
```

When ever I run it on Access I get a Syntax error 'Missing Operator'. 
Also are there any alternatives to Access that I can import data from an excel spread sheet?

Comment: MS Access has a tricky way to join more than 2 tables. Use parentheses somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.  In MS Access, yes.  It likes extra parentheses, probably because the database developers don't believe in readability:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Movies INNER JOIN
      Sessions
      ON Movies.MovieID = Sessions.MovieID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Tickets
     ON Sessions.SessionID = Tickets.SessionID;
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that out after I did the design version and then went into SQL view and it had extra brackets. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable OPENROWSET if you have a local instance of SQL, and install MDACs (I would install both x86 and x64 if you have a 64 bit pc). Below is a link to an article that will help you get setup. Also, be sure to run the management studio with elevated privileges.

[How to enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544221/how-to-enable-ad-hoc-distributed-queries)

Below is how the query would look. In my example I use Excel 8.0 instead of 12 because the column names are addressable in my select statements for 8.

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                   'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Temp\MyExcelDoc.xlsx;', 
                   'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export data from an excel spreadsheet into a number of formats.  I find two of the best to be;

- Comma Separated Values (CSV)
- XML

In many cases, you can deal with the data directly from the Excell spreadsheet. 
It really depends on what you want to do.

Your SQL query looks fine - but with Access you need to do the extra joins in brackets;

```
SELECT * FROM ((Movies 
INNER JOIN Sessions ON Movies.MovieID=Sessions.MovieID)
INNER JOIN Tickets ON Sessions.SessionID=Tickets.SessionID)
;
```