# Variable Syntax for server name

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pass the server name as a variable in a `Exec(@sqlstring)` stored procedure. However I cannot get the correct syntax and I'm pretty much all out of ideas.

The server name is UK-DATA-SQL-P01 or UK-DATA-SQL-P02 which is why I need to use it as a variable so the user can select.

The syntax I'm trying to use to pass the variable is:

```
INNER JOIN ' + @ServerName + '.' + @DBName + '.[dbo].
```

I'm sure that this is simple but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to add the error I keep seeing is: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: Correct, as mention on the first line of my post.

Comment: In that case I edited your question so that is clear. Also you should put `[]` around your server and database names the same as you do with `dbo`.

Comment: @Carlos80 check my answer

Comment: Thanks Igor, yes I have tried that but still get the same error: Incorrect syntax near '1'. The actual variable I'm trying to pass through from front end looks like [UK-DATA-SQL-P01]

Comment: `@@SERVERNAME` is the correct "variable" name to get it. Also, when building dynamic queries like that, remember to use `QUOTENAME` on each identifier to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Then it could be something else in your query, possibly a second join you did not escape or who knows what because that method of escaping works. example: `'INNER JOIN [' + @ServerName + '].[' + @DBName + '].[dbo].`

Comment: You may be right Igor, as I have tried you suggestion above using the     [' +@ServerName + '] suggestion and I'm still getting the same error. Strange thing is when I right this out with fixed server names it works fine, as soon as I try and turn them into variables I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this just a sample then you can extend

```
   create proc  sampleProc 
    @tableName varchar(100) ,
    @serverName varchar(100)
    as 
    begin

    declare @tableName1 varchar(100)
    set @tableName1='Sales'
    declare @fullname varchar(500)

    set @fullname = @serverName+'.'+ @tableName
    print (@fullname)       

    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)

    SET @SQLQuery = ' SELECT * FROM '+ @fullname + ' inner join ' + @tableName1 + ' on id=custid'

    print (@SQLQuery)

    --EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)

    end


    --usage  like this 
    exec sampleProc 'server','customer'


    declare @tableName varchar(100)
    set @tableName='Customers'

    -- this is previous answer 

    declare @tableName1 varchar(100)
    set @tableName1='Sales'

    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)

    SET @SQLQuery = ' SELECT * FROM '+ @tableName + ' inner join ' + @tableName1 + ' on id=custid'

    print (@SQLQuery)

    EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: Thanks Yashveer, how do I make a variable (@tableName) a variable as the user has a number of servers that they can run this report on?

Comment: his tablename is variable  you just need to pass the different name when you execute on different server may be using in stores procedure .

Comment: let me try to add it in answer .

Comment: @Carlos80 please check now I added a stored proc which you can call multiple times with difrent variables I hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **OPENDATASOURCE**. Something like this :

`INNER JOIN OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB','Data Source = ServerName; User ID = Username; Password = Password').[DatabaseName].[DatabaseOwner].[TableName] Z ON...`

PS. You'd need to enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries for this to work.

[How To Enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544221/how-to-enable-ad-hoc-distributed-queries) - For Reference

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Synonyms to achieve similar:

```
Create Procedure ReturnServerDbTable (@Server as nvarchar(50), @DB as nvarchar(50), @Table as nvarchar(50))
as
begin
declare @sql as nvarchar(500)
set @sql = 'CREATE SYNONYM ServerDBTable FOR ' + @Server + '.' + @db + '.dbo.' + @table 
exec(@sql)
select * from ServerDBTable
DROP SYNONYM ServerDBTable
end
```