# Transferring data from one server to another without linking servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a stored procedure that will query a server that I only have read access to.

Is this possible using SQL?  If so, how?

The answers from [Insert Data From One Server To Another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285391/insert-data-from-one-server-to-another) and [Export table data from one SQL Server to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009189/export-table-data-from-one-sql-server-to-another) seem to only be helpful if I had more permissions in the source server. If I am mistaken, please correct me.

Comment: To use sql you Need a linked servers, alternatives  are an etl tool such as ssis, script to read data and reimport such as perl/php/python, or to export a sql results to csv and import into destination server.

Comment: Thanks.  I was pretty sure that the answer was no before asking, but on the off chance that it was yes or if I had misunderstood the directionality of permissions, then that would be cool.

Comment: Would it be improper to ask why linked servers are required for querying cross-server if the authentication mode is "Windows Authentication"?